# Why is my SSL certificate saying it's not totally secure?

Tags: iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've just installed a SSL certificate on my web site, but when I view it in my browser (Chrome), the browser warns me that it's not totally secure:

[image: Browser warning]

What am I doing wrong, and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything with a reference to non-https links will invalidate the site.

This includes all css, images, js etc.

For Google Analytics see - http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55483 for secure tracking

Also see similar post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028785/what-can-invalidate-ssl-php-jquery

Comment: Thanks - answer credit for the link to the Google Analytics FAQ!

Answer (score 1):

Because you reference objects that are not fetched over https, or are served via a server with a self-signed or expired certificate. Usually googles analytics.js or similar.

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or something similar to determine what the objects are.

Comment: Aha, so using Google Analytics invalidates your SSL?  That could be it...

Comment: Including non ssl objects will cause these warnings, yes.